# Будет ли запускаться на windows 64 в virtualbox ubuntu 32?

Tags: virtualbox

Не пользовался раньше virtualbox. У меня windows 64. При запуске virtualbox предлагает создать только 32 разрядные системы. Скачал дистрибутив ubuntu 32 разрядный, пытаюсь запустить - после запуска появляется ошибка и виртуальная система не хочет работать.

Comment: Проверьте версию virtualbox / скачайте с  virtualbox.org. Всё есть - весь спектр систем и под 32 и под 64. Проверьте хост на вирусы.